# Auth0 - verify JWT

Tags: java, jwt, openid-connect, auth0

I'm trying to verify my JWT returned from OpenID flow using Auth0 libraries.
This is my code:

```
@Test
void verify() {
    final String token = "eyJraWQiOiJpc2FjLW9pZGMiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2lzYWMuc3ZpbnQuaW5mb2NlcnQuaXQiLCJzdWIiOiJNMDE0MDE2OCIsImF1ZCI6IkVDT01NRVJDRSIsImV4cCI6MTU5NDkwNTc4OSwiaWF0IjoxNTk0OTA1NDg5LCJqdGkiOiJ2SmljeGNSTkQ1RkVCd3BGVzE2TWF3IiwibmJmIjoxNTk0OTA1MzY5LCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1OTQ5MDU0ODN9.EsK6lR9vHtLWAeoKvBL_ipJJqvzJMKCOKSPMUUcSK4W7MStQHQc0TlN20-2P8reCi69zQ-R2Fn2V_i-JnH8N1rz_Ar-SdX4ghI2BStOL8Z1Sl3iZZ3VV7dJBqAvrq5mZXTj7bdzbFwdDIEdSVYTrEDvJuNIOYP0e7RSQ5Hi-QA6tatW5_ir3DrSYDACNcXE1sacvdA2onIsyw1UrD1XW9nqsZSn4wWA0totQGJcA1FYjQb0-28Ttkt2P_5uYaX_VDojKQVfhUTJZQKGeKjBpRCVmV__I1U-nVhSnP5UcgCnjbJkO72aIGLWj7I0lLJF2gSmicfqmrAlu8MHMokAmxw";
    final String publicKey = "??"
    try {

        byte[] publicBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKey);
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);

        final Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) pubKey, null);
        final JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                .withIssuer("https://isac.svint.infocert.it")
                .build(); //Reusable verifier instance
        final DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
        logger.info("{}", jwt);
    } catch (JWTVerificationException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException exception) {
        //Invalid signature/claims
        Assertions.fail(exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now, I'm not sure about the correct procedure for obtaining public key.
Following OpenID / Oauth2 protocol, the identity provider expose this API:

```
{{endporint}}/keys

{
    "keys": [
        {
            "kty": "RSA",
            "kid": "myidp-oidc",
            "use": "sig",
            "alg": "RS256",
            "n": "<some_value>",
            "e": "AQAB"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I use the above info to obtain key and verify JWT ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had to import on pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And then:

```
final String token = "<some_token>";

try {

    final DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.decode(token);
    final JwkProvider provider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL("<endpoint_idp>/keys"));
    final Jwk jwk = provider.get(decodedJWT.getKeyId());
    final Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);

    final JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
            .withIssuer("<issue>")
            .build(); //Reusable verifier instance
    final DecodedJWT verifiedJWT = verifier.verify(token);
    logger.info("{}", verifiedJWT);
} catch (JWTVerificationException | JwkException | MalformedURLException exception) {
    //Invalid signature/claims
    Assertions.fail(exception.getMessage());
}
```